# shows me blank page when upload a .docx document on a website laravel

Tags: laravel-5, uploading

Hello I am new to laravel and still learning it and I come across different problems and issues and I cant find a way to solve it. I have been stuck to this since very long. Any help would be much appreciated.

## The Problem

Whenever I upload a .docx file to my website i get a blank page without any error or without the content of that docx file. I dont know what the problem is. Please help me out with this.

## Code

```
   public function getUploadedFile() {
     
     // $destinationPath = 'uploads';
    // $path= public_path()."/". $destinationPath;

    // $content = utf8_encode(File::get('/var/www/html/asad/File-Uploader/public/uploads/detailed_period_report_template.xls'));
    // return view('/files', compact('path'));
    

    $file = $this->request->file('file_name');
    $file_name = $this->request->file_name;

    if (File::isFile($file_name))
    {
        $file_name = File::get($file_name);
        $response = Response::make($file_name, 200);
         $content_types = [
            'application/octet-stream', // txt etc
            'application/msword', // doc
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', //docx
            'application/vnd.ms-excel', // xls
            'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', // xlsx
            'application/pdf', // pdf
        ];
        // using this will allow you to do some checks on it (if pdf/docx/doc/xls/xlsx)
       $response->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');

        return $response;
    }
```

I dont have any view for this. Do I need one for this ? If yes what would be it like because every docx file has it's set of properties like font, size, etc unlike excel sheets where we just defines columns. Please help me out. Thank you in advance

Comment: this is my view to click on the file though ... might be doing something wrong here but I dont think so but just in case ...

`<td><a href="/open-uploaded-file"> {{ $upload['file_name'] }} </a></td>`

Comment: Add an `else{ ... }` block after your `if (File::isFile($file_name){ }` where you'll return an error response about the file not being found. See if this returns the error (meaning the file is not present).

Comment: ya I just added `else {
            Session::flash("message", "File Not found");
            return redirect("\home");
        }` 
and it says "file not found"

Comment: So there you have your culprit. You need to make sure you know where the file is stored.

Comment: I know where the file is stored but I am not getting the way to give it that path so that it can fetch out the file. If you see third line in the code, it is the path of the file which I have commented out after trying out every single possibility I could. I tried un-commenting and doing it but still the same blank page or path not found

Comment: If you know where the file is located and the file is really there then the problem is not with Laravel returning blank page. The problem is the file can not be located.

Comment: so where am I going wrong in the code ? I can't help it ... :(

Comment: this is what I did now `$file = $this->request->file('file_name');
            $file_name = $this->request->file_name;
            $file= public_path(). "/uploads/" . $file_name;
            $files = File::get($file);
            $response = Response::make($files, 200);`

now it says "FileNotFoundException in Filesystem.php line 41: File does not exist at path /var/www/html/asad/File-Uploader/public/uploads/" 
But if I remove this line of code `$files = File::get($file);`it opens a file with this "/var/www/html/File-Uploader/public/uploads/"

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out after so long finally.

It was sending "null" as a file name so what I did now is got the file name from the database instead of storage and then compared it that if that file is in storage and database then open it. Below is the code running for me now.
Thank you @MATEY for all your help though

```
        $upload = new Upload;

        $file= public_path(). "/uploads/" . $upload->file_name = $this->request->file_name;
        //dd($file);

        $files = File::get($file);
        $response = Response::make($files, 200);
```

and changed the content type to `$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');`

Thank you for the all help @MATEY. You gave me the motivation to fix it plus your `else{...}` part missing in `if` condition actually helped me alot finding out the error.